# How to update the index column of GlobalSecondaryIndex DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, yaml

I need to change the index column of GlobalSecondaryIndex in DynamoDB. At first, I just change the "AttributeName" of GSI. It didn't work. Then I researched online and found that I should delete the current GSI and create a new GSI. Here, I use `IndexStatus: DELETING` to remove the current GSI. However, it always showed error:**Encountered unsupported property IndexStatus**. So how to fix this error? I'm coding in yaml.

Answer (score 1):

To change the column of a GSI you'll have to use a two step process.

1. Remove the GSI from your table.
2. Add the GSI back to the table with the new column.

Because your question is tagged with `yaml` I assume you are using CloudFormation, or some form of IaC. You'll need to remove the GSI, deploy the change without the GSI, add the GSI with the new column, and deploy that.

A safer approach might be to create a new GSI with the new column.

1. Add the new GSI with the new column and deploy the table
2. Update your code to use the new GSI and deploy the new code
3. Remove the old GSI with the old column and deploy the table

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. How to remove the GSI?

Comment: You need to provide more information if you need help with that. If it's CloudFormation you just need to remove it from the template. In the console you just select the GSI and delete it. There is a CLI command to delete it. It depends on how you are managing your table, which you didn't say.

Comment: It's CloudFormation. I'm using serverless.yaml.

Comment: Then you just need to remove the GSI from the template and redeploy it. If you can include a snippet of the YAML that is the table I can tell you what you need to remove.